# bizcharts y-xis label override

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, charts

using bizcharts facing issu y-xis label override.
the value are : 1991, 1992...., I want only show 3 value in y-axis

```
const data = [
                  { year: "1991", value: 3 },
                  { year: "1992", value: 4 },
                  { year: "1993", value: 3.5 },
                  { year: "1994", value: 5 },
                  { year: "1995", value: 4.9 },
                  { year: "1996", value: 6 },
                  { year: "1997", value: 7 },
                  { year: "1998", value: 9 },
                  { year: "1999", value: 13 }
                ];
                const cols = {
                  'value': { min: 0 },
                  'year': {range: [ 0 , 1]}
                };
```

screenshot of problem
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

found solution of this problem, by using tickCount in yaer object, like this tickCount:3,

```
const data = [
              { year: "1991", value: 3 },
              { year: "1992", value: 4 },
              { year: "1993", value: 3.5 },
              { year: "1994", value: 5 },
              { year: "1995", value: 4.9 },
              { year: "1996", value: 6 },
              { year: "1997", value: 7 },
              { year: "1998", value: 9 },
              { year: "1999", value: 13 }
            ];
            const cols = {
              'value': { min: 0 },
              'year': {range: [ 0 , 1], tickCount:3}
            };
```

screenshot
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can change style in the object `cols`:

```
const cols = {
    'value': { min: 0 },
    'year': {
         range: [ 0 , 1],
         ticks:["1991", "1994", "1997", "1999"],
    }
};
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, but i need any 3 option pic from label, like as most left is 1991 and center is 1995 and most right is 1999 something like this [1991------1995------1999]